# Xcopy how to stop when destination nonexistent

Tags: batch-file, cmd

As of now I have:

```
FOR %%A IN ("C:\test1" "C:\test4" "C:\test3" "C:\test2") DO XCOPY /S /Y /E "C:\test" %%A
```

I want to make this stop when it reaches a directory that does not yet exist and display an error message, then allow the user to press a key to continue down the list, NOT prompt the user whether it is a file or directory being targeted.

I know of `/I` but I don't want the directory to be created at all, just for the program to stop and prompt whether to continue copying or not.

For example: If `C:\test1` does not exist, have the program stop and notify the user, then ask them to press a key to continue on to `C:\test4`, `C:\test3`, and so on.

I'm not very well versed in making batch scripts, and I barely managed to get this working.

EDIT: Basically, instead of asking whether it's a file or directory, it just says "Directory nonexistent! Press any key to continue."

Comment: Why not just check if the directory exists before running the xcopy?

Comment: To be honest, I don't see a need to stop and tell the user either.  Stopping would make sense if you wanted to ask if the user wanted to create the missing directory.  You can still report the directory missing via echo if you plan on redirecting to a log under normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a run:

```
@echo off
FOR %%A IN ("C:\test1" "C:\test4" "C:\test3" "C:\test2") DO (
   if exist "%%~A\" (
      XCOPY /S /Y /E "C:\test" %%A
    ) else (
      echo Directory nonexistent! Press any key to continue.
      pause>nul
   )
)
```